# use different title and caption text on colorbox

Tags: title, colorbox

Using colorbox, it shows the link title below the image.

```
<a href='link.to.my.image' class='colorbox' title='image title'>
<img src='link.to.thumbnail' alt='thumb alt' title='thumb title' />
```

In above code example, when I move with the mouse over the thumbnail (and link), the tooltip shows "image title".
When I click on the thumbnail, it open colorbox window and shows the image and blow the text "image title" as caption.

So far so good.

If I have a more detailed text I want to show as caption icluding html tags like strong or br, it also shows that without tag interpreting when I move with the mouse over the thumbnail (and link).

My question now is, if there is a possibility to use 1 title to be shown as tooltip whith mouse over thumbnail but a different tag shown as caption below image.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I was wrong and had no idea what gone wrong before. Mouseover thumbnail shows title of thumbnail, not of link.